# Order by operation cost

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

I have a 73 GB big table `table1` . Most of my queries involve fetching the latest 100 entries in the table which satisfy some condition. I am using Django as my backend for this web app. My query is something similar to this:

```
table_object = table1.objects.filter(first_filter_field=6)
order_by = '-created_on'
table_object = .filter(not_null_field__isnull=False).order_by(order_by)
table_object = table_object[offset:(offset + limit)]
```

I think this query takes too much time.

1. How can I measure the time taken by this query? (in Postgres)
2. How can I improve its performance? I just need latest 100 creatives which satisfy some condition (basically WHERE statement addition in normal query.)

I am new to Django, so please be descriptive and give links to the related material wherever possible.

Comment: you should provide the schema of the table so that we know how to write a better query

Comment: @ArpitSolanki only these three fields are of interest to me , what else information do you want . Will creating an index on created on help ?

Comment: The answer given below by pranjal is perfect. Refer to that.

Answer (score 4):

**1)** You can use something called [EXPLAIN ANALYZE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html). This'll help you. Refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063402/get-execution-time-of-postgresql-query) for more info.
**2)** Use [db_index=True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786413/add-indexes-db-index-true) while creating an attribute. This'll help you speed up searches as it indexes the column to which it is added. 

 **Note** - For the primary key column, db_index=True is by default. However, you add db_index=True for more than one column.