# When we should use "db_index=True" in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

When we should define `db_index=True` on a model fields ?

I'm trying to optimize the application & I want to learn more about `db_index`, in which conditions we should use it ?

The documentation says that using `db_index=True` on model fields is used to speed up the lookups with slightly disadvantages with storage and memory.

Should we use `db_index=True` only on those fields that have unique values like the primary field `id` ? 
What happens if we enabled indexing for those fields which are not unique and contains repetitive data ?

Comment: This is an extremely complicated question. It depends on the database you are using, the data you are storing, how you are querying the data, how many writes/reads you are performing, it goes on... usually it is a case of tweaking things here and there until you get the performance you desire. As a simple rule though: any fields that you will be consistently filtering on will benefit from being indexed

Comment: A very similar question: [Add Indexes db_index=True](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14786413/4744341)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I would say you should it when you have a field that is unique for fast lookups.

e.g., You have a table of `customers` with many`users`. Each row representing a user will have their own unique `user_id`. When you create an index, a pointer is created within the DB to where that data is stored so that the next look up won't take as long.
Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) to learn more

Comment: Most databases add an index for foreign keys automatically anyway

Comment: In other words you use `db_index=True` if you are going to use `Entity.objects.get(some_field=some_value)` .

Answer (score 12):

When you set `db_index=True` on some field, queries based on that field would be much faster **O(log(n))** instead **O(n)**.
Under the hood, it is usually implemented using [B-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree).

The trade-off for these accelerated queries is increased memory usage and time for writes. So the best use case for indexing would be if you have a read-heavy table that is often queried by non-primary field.

Answer (score 7):

You should use `db_index=True` when you use `unique=True`, there is a specific reason to use it,

By using this method you can boost a little bit of performance,

When we fire a query in SQL, finding starts from the top to bottom

Case: 'Without db_index=True':
It will search and filter till all bottom rows even if we find the data

Case: 'With db_index=True':
When Object finds it will just stop their

It will boost a little bit of performance

Comment: You dont have to specify db_index=True when unique=True.  Take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#unique