# Queries too slow on PostegreSQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql, performance

I'm currently working on a project, using Django for web development and PostgreSQL as a database. I have noticed that queries on my system are starting to slow down as the amount of data increases.

My main table, say `Produto`, has millions of records, and simple queries like product listing are taking longer than I would like. I've already added some indexes to the relevant columns, but I still feel there's room for improvement.

Here are my models:

```py
class Produto(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    descricao = models.TextField()
    preco = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    estoque = models.IntegerField()

class Pedido(models.Model):
    produtos = models.ManyToManyField(Produto)
    data_pedido = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And this is the query I'm doing:

```
produtos = Produto.objects.filter(estoque__gt=0).order_by('-preco')[:10]
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I optimize this query?

Comment: What are the table definitions? Without knowing what indices you've created, it's impossible to know if the query should operate efficiently or not.

Comment: Implement pagination so your entire dataset is not loaded at once.

Comment: @Mess: AFAICT, the Django ORM already handles this; when you slice a query like the OP is doing with `[:10]`, it automatically applies a `LIMIT 10` to the underlying query sent to the DB, it's not fetching the whole table, then slicing off the first 10 items.

Comment: Could you please share the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) for your SQL statement? And the statement itself and the ddl for the tables and indexes involved. All in plain text as an update to your question

Comment: You didn't provide `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the SQL statement, so there is little anybody can do besides guessing.

Answer (score 1):

You need [database indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59596176/when-we-should-use-db-index-true-in-django). Without an index PostgreSQL needs to do a full table scan when checking for `estoque__gt=0` and also when ordering by `-preco`:

```py
class Produto(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    descricao = models.TextField()
    preco = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, db_index=True)
    estoque = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
```

Don't forget to run `makemigrations` and `migrate` after this change.

You may also consider a [functional (partial) index](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/indexes/#django.db.models.Index.expressions) if you frequently filter by `estoque__gt=0`.